# Using Tornado web to access a HTTP stream and serve streamed data to web clients

Tags: python, tornado, websocket

I would like to use the Tornado web server to connect to a HTTP stream like the [Twitter Stream](http://dev.twitter.com/pages/streaming_api_methods) and serve the streamed data via websockets to a web client.

I've got both working seperatly, one Tornado instance using [twitstream](https://github.com/atl/twitstream) and the other using [tornado.websocket.WebSocketHandler](https://github.com/facebook/tornado/blob/master/tornado/websocket.py), but i would like both services combined in one Tornado instance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you start a separate thread and use that thread to push messages to the WebSocket listeners, that will solve your problem